# How to convert a boundary box hexa value to integer?

Tags: python, int, hex, converters

This is a XML file in which I would like to get the boundary box coordinate using python. You can see that there is a BBox attribute which contains (x1,y1,x2,y2) in hexical string.

[image: This is a XML file in which I would like to get the boundary box coordinate using python. You can see that there is a BBox attribute which contains (x1,y1,x2,y2) in hexical string.]

I parse the boundary box information using python but the problem is how can I convert this 16 digit hexa value to human readable integer value which we are familiar to see as an object boundary coordinate value.

[image]

I used `int('hex str', 16)` but it gives a big integer value which is obviously not like as a coordinate value of 800x1200 size image. In this case, the BBox first value was '4074145c00000005' and I got after convert  4644359501095370757.

Please give me a solution how to convert this boundary box coordinate into human understandable integer value.

Comment: Would be helpful to know what this values actually mean. Obviously they aren't pixel positions/sizes. By the way: Show code and data as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: This BBox value is Table coordinates of images which I found in Marmot dataset and they already mentioned those are table coordinates in hexical string.

Comment: These numbers must be measured in some unit. The XML data format documentation should tell which it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to convert this 16 digit hexical string to human understandable decimal/integer value. This value representation use IEEE 784 standard conversion which explained in [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings). This 16 digit hexa value used to represent float point conversion for more accurate coordinate position.

```
tab = ['0000000000000000', '408a500000000000', '4082980000000000', '0000000000000000']
int_val = [int(struct.unpack('!d', str(t).decode('hex'))[0]) for t in tab]
print "convert to int : ", int_val
```

The function `struct.unpack(format, buffer)` use to convert which has two parameter. First parameter is for format `!d` which `d` means  Double in C or float in python and `!` sign use to indicate Byte Order.There are 5 Byte Orders `@, =, <, >, !` use to represent which format I need to convert.